# Trimming each line in a text file to 30 characters

Tags: batch-file, trim

I have text file like below

### Input sample text file

> 69273ww01/080-100 1021/00 11123
>   80381ew20/937-134 1372/92 12737298323
>   02ws88749/263-379 2836/39 121
>   4793de592/343-283 7384/49 233792740562263

### Required output text file

> 69273ww01/080-100 1021/00 111
>   80381ew20/937-134 1372/92 127
>   02ws88749/263-379 2836/39 121
>   4793de592/343-283 7384/49 233

I want to take each line and remove everything after the 30th character in the line. Unfortunately, I don't know where to start. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: In your example, you are trimming the _third_ word in each line. Which is it?

Comment: Actually I want to trim on the bases of length not on words.

Comment: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.LeftString and http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html, but inside a `for` loop, you'll need http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Comment: I'm afraid in your output sample there are not 30 characters per line...

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q34959432.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
 FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
  SET "line=%%a"
  ECHO(!line:~0,30!
 )
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q34959432.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Your posted data-out is 29 characters long, not 30. The changes you would need to make should be obvious.